# How to combine these two if statements for Google Sheets

Tags: if-statement, google-sheets, boolean, nested-if, ifs

I want to combine these two if statements so that the cell returns "Home" if C1=E1, "Not Home" if C1<>E1, but ignores blank cells, so the cell returns blank if either C1 or E1 is blank.

```
=if(AND(C1=E1, C1<>"", E1<>""),"Home","")
=if(AND(C1<>E1, C1<>"", E1<>""),"Not Home","")
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
=IF((C1="")+(E1="");;IF(C1=E1; "Home"; "Not Home"))
```